# How image_tag is overrided and a reason to not add fingerprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets, actionviewhelper

I have rails application, with sass less and many gems.

I try to find where **image_tag** is overwrited to debug why it do not add **fingerprint** hash to url.

I have done `rails assets:precompile` and files with hash fingerprint are existing in public dir.
The problem is on production and in development which I configured (as in production) like this:

```rb
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

I tried to search in `~/.gem/gems` and `~/.gem/bundler/gems/` and in project folder for `def image_tag` and `:image_tag` - no results except place where it is actually defined (`actionview-5.0.7.2/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb`).

I tried to print some from `image_tag` at `asset_tag_helper.rb` - no any output, however at `asset_path` in `asset_url_helper.rb` output is present but no any image files processed.

Same time `image_tag` works correct and generate correct tag with options like `:size` and so on. But do not contain a hash fingerprint

Comment: You need to provide an example which reproduces the behavior your talking about. Otherwise we are just dealing with hypotheticals.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint right before calling `image_tag` using byebug or pry and then call `method(:image_tag).source_location` to see where it's defined, but I don't get why you say it's being overriden. You should show your code.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is solved. It was a `path` - first param of `image_tag`. When the path begin from `/` (like `/img.png`) - this mean an url do not checked for an assets existence and do not modified with a digest. When path is not begin from `/` (like `img.png`) then it is checked for assets and the digest is added.

The second problem is not solved. There is no way how to find where actual `image_tag` function is defined and where and how it is overrided.